# python stacking data with missing values in the header

Tags: python

I have data that is imported from a csv file, in reality there are more columns and more cycles, but this is a representative snippet:

```
Export date 2020-10-10                                  
    Record #3           Record #2           Record #1       
    Cycle #5            Cycle #4            Cycle #3        
time ( min.)    Parameter1  Something2  Whatever3   Parameter1  Something2  Whatever3   Parameter1  Something2  Whatever3
0   0.0390625   9.89619 0.853909    14.409  10.1961 0.859037    14.4676 10.0274 0.832598
1   0.0390625   9.53452 0.949844    14.4096 10.3034 1.224   14.4676 10.0323 1.20403
2   0.0390625   9.8956  1.47227 14.4097 10.6586 1.14486 14.4676 10.4936 1.12747
3   0.0390625   10.7829 1.44412 14.4097 10.9185 1.20247 14.5116 10.6892 1.12459
```

The top part of the data contains a row (`export date`) that is not needed in the table.
I would like to stack the data so that there will be `Cycle` and `Record` columns. The problem is that these values are found only above the first column of data for every cycle. For example, Cycle5 has three columns of data, then Cycle4 has three columns of data etc.

This is how the output should look like:

[image]

I didn't get very far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cycles.csv')  
#Fill the names of cycles to the right
df.ffill(axis = 1, inplace = True)

#Not sure this is needed, it might make it easier to melt/stack
df.iloc[0,0] = "time ( min.)"
df.iloc[1,0] = "time ( min.)"
```

Thank you for your thoughts and assistance!!

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: I've added the code I have so far to the posting (not much I'm afraid...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of problems with this which you need to address all:

### Firstly Read all the required info:

This cannot be done unless all of the info is read separately:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
string = open('SO.csv').read()
records = [i.split('#')[1].strip() for i in string.split('\n')[1].split(',') if '#' in i]
cycles  = [i.split('#')[1].strip() for i in string.split('\n')[2].split(',') if '#' in i]
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), sep=',', header=3).dropna(how = 'any')
```

### Rename columns so they follow a pattern:

```
cols = [col for col in data.columns if '.' not in col]
data = data.rename(columns = dict(zip(cols ,[col+'.0' for col in cols])))
```

### Build a loop to pluck out records for each record and cycle:

```
dfs = []
for rdx, rec in enumerate(records):
    df = data[['time ( min.)'].__add__([col for col in data.columns if col.endswith(str(rdx))])].rename(columns = dict(zip([col+f'.{rdx}' for col in cols],cols)))
    df[['Cycle', 'Record']] = cycles[rdx], records[rdx]
    dfs.append(df)
```

### Finally Merge them all:

```
pd.concat(dfs)
```

This results in:

```
time ( min.)    Parameter1  Something2  Whatever3   Cycle   Record
0   0.0 0.039062    9.89619 0.853909    5   3
1   1.0 0.039062    9.53452 0.949844    5   3
2   2.0 0.039062    9.89560 1.472270    5   3
3   3.0 0.039062    10.78290    1.444120    5   3
0   0.0 14.409000   10.19610    0.859037    4   2
1   1.0 14.409600   10.30340    1.224000    4   2
2   2.0 14.409700   10.65860    1.144860    4   2
3   3.0 14.409700   10.91850    1.202470    4   2
0   0.0 14.467600   10.02740    0.832598    3   1
1   1.0 14.467600   10.03230    1.204030    3   1
2   2.0 14.467600   10.49360    1.127470    3   1
3   3.0 14.511600   10.68920    1.124590    3   1
```

Breaking down a problem in simple steps will not only help you go with this one but also in EVERY OTHER case. Just figure out what you need to do, break into steps and go with it!

Comment: Thank you @User5 ! This is very helpful!  When executing your suggested code I get an error at line: df[['Cycle', 'Record']] = cycles[rdx], records[rdx] the error stated: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Cycle', 'Record'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]".

Comment: Try doing in two steps:
`df['Cycle'] = cycles[rdx]`

`df['Record'] = records[rdx]`

Comment: Thank you! it fixed it and your answer was really helpful!!